# Preview page not shown in webforms

Tags: webform-civicrm

I'm trying to show the preview page in a CiviCRM Webform and it's not working. I have activated the option in Webform > Form settings > Preview Page but when I press the Send button it goes directly to the thanks page.

I'm using CiviCRM 4.6.10 and Webform CiviCRM Integration 7.x-4.15

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the error: In the preview's page configuration, when the "Preview button label" is set to the value "Submit", then there's a bug and the webform thinks it's the submit button and not the preview page one.

It's really strange. We have opened a bug: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18237

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hi Just tested the same preview against same version of Civicrm 4.6.10 and webform integration 7.x-4.15 works find

Both in Pay-later option and also using an payment processor

I guess you need to look for any PHP error log and also look for any Ajax issue - thanks